# SQL Join to return results where no match occurs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table A and a table B. I want to join A to B but only need results where the join is not possible. I have tried

```
    SELECT B.* 
      FROM A 
RIGHT JOIN B ON A.KEY = B.KEY 
     WHERE A.KEY IS NULL
```

This should work but it doesn't. Is my SQL above correct?

Comment: How can you join on a key of `null`?

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: I think it won't work because `A.KEY = B.KEY` won't work when `A.KEY` is null, because you can't use = to compare NULL values. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: @BenM, it's an outer join. When the join fails because there is no key in A for a given key in B, A.key is possibly the only column guaranteed to be null because the join failed. A.othercolumn might be null because it's just null (but all the other columns in that row have a value)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: How the `Key` can be `NULL`?

Comment: @Sami probably A.KEY is a foreign key to B.KEY. Null foreign keys are allowed. Null primary keys generally are not.

Comment: @CaiusJard see the link posted by ADyson.

Comment: @BenM unless I'm missing something really obvious, this is the standard way to look for "rows in B that have no matching row in A" though i'd much prefer it written with a left join

Comment: @CaiusJard the issue is the use of `=` to compare `null` values.

Comment: @RadimBača It just returns all results for table B

Comment: @BenM where does the query use `= NULL` to compare null values? The where clause clearly says `IS NULL`

Comment: The join uses `=`...

Comment: @BenM you have used SQL before, right?

Comment: `I want to join A to B but only need results where the join is not possible.` Do you mean: 1) in A, but not in B 2) In B, but not in A 3) in A or B, but not both

Comment: @wildplasser see my FULL OUTER JOIN example in my answer. Whatever point BenM is driving at is unlikely to be relevant to you

Comment: @CaiusJard Not really, to be honest. Just for 15 years.

Comment: @BenM You're just a newbie then ;)

Comment: @CaiusJard Haha it would have been longer, but I happen to have a penchant for NoSQL 

Comment: @BenM I keep thinking about getting into it, but maybe I'm just too old school wedded to Oracle. It's a form of Stockholm Syndrome I'm sure - i was kept in a basement writing Oracle reports for 5 years in my early career, and then I fell in love with it and using any other RDBMS feels like cheating :O

Comment: @CaiusJard You should try it out, gets around all this `IS NULL` nonsense ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say what you mean by "didn't work", but if either of these queries:

```
SELECT B.* 
 FROM A 
RIGHT JOIN B ON A.KEY = B.KEY 
 WHERE A.KEY IS NULL

SELECT A.* 
 FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.KEY = B.KEY 
 WHERE B.KEY IS NULL
```

return no results, it means that every key in the solid table is matched with at least one key in the outer joined table.

If you're trying to find rows in either A or B, that have no matching row in the other, you'll need a query like:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, CASE WHEN A.KEY IS NULL THEN 'in B but not A' WHEN B.KEY IS NULL THEN 'in B but not A' END as explanation
 FROM A 
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.KEY = B.KEY 
 WHERE A.KEY IS NULL OR B.KEY IS NULL
```

You might hear people saying "but, a key can never be null because that's what a key is for/primary keys cannot be null!" - yes, but we're doing a join; theyre primary keys in the table, but theyre not necessarily primary keys after a join has occurred. The database will be perfectly happy to generate a row full of `NULL` values for B (including the b.key column) paired with a row full of actual values from A, if there is no row in B where the key is equal to the value of a.key - this means the key of the table is no longer a key of the join, and it's allowed to be `NULL`.

Could you test on null against another column than key? Yes, but unless that other column in the table is NOT NULLABLE the key column is the best one to use if you're looking for mismatched rows. This is because it's the only column that we can guarantee will contain a null in the situation where the two tables are joined, and there's no data in this table to match with the other table.

To better explain, here is some data:

```
A
key|val
-------
000|hello
001|world

B
key|val
-------
000|hello
002|there
```

- If these two tables are `INNER JOINED`, only row 000 will be the result
- If these two tables are `A LEFT JOIN B ON A.KEY=B/KEY WHERE B.KEY IS NULL`, row 001 will be the result
- If these two tables are `A RIGHT JOIN B ON A.KEY=B/KEY WHERE A.KEY IS NULL`, row 002 will be the result
- If these two tables are full `OUTER JOIN`'ed where a or b key is `NULL`, rows 001 and 002 will be the result

If the `key` column in either A or B contains `NULL`, that row will never appear in join results.

Comment: Thanks for this this detailed answer!

Comment: Even though this was not what the op needed in the end, I'm glad you posted it as it helped me when I found the ops post searching my own problem. Kudos for keeping your sense of humour.

Answer (score -4):

Found the answer.

The reason this was not working is because I was using the AND condition on the JOIN and not in the WHEREclause.

Thanks everyone anyway!

Comment: So you posted up a "not working" query that *wasn't actually the query you were running*? Oh dear..

Comment: Exactly, your original snippet didn't even have an `AND` condition?!

Comment: I tried to simplify it to make this easier for people answering. Sorry, I will delete if possible.

Comment: Well, it amused me at least :) #mighthavedonethatbeforemyself